# How to access a website that is deployed in a Windows instance in EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created a Windows instance in EC2, also installed the Bitnami WAMP stack there. The web app runs on the instance, however it does not display on a browser outside the instance with the public IP of the instance.

I have configured the Security Groups this way:
Port 80 (HTTP inbound and outbound)
Port 443 (HTTPS inbound and outbound).

What else need to be done, in order to display the web app on a browser? Thanks

Comment: How’s the VPC setup look like ? Do you have IGW, public subnet ?

Comment: The default VPC security group has all traffic (inbound and outbound), I don´t have IGW neither a public subnet. What could be missing? Thanks.

Comment: You have to have a IGW attached with your VPC so that your subnets can talk to internet. Configure your route table to have routed traffic to and from IGW and you might be able to talk to your instances from outside.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by disable the Firewalls on the Windows O.S directly (instance).